# Как реализовать вывод абсолютно разных статей?

Tags: php, mysql

Никак не могу понять, допустим у меня есть блог, в нем есть статьи, они в бд хранятся как id, title, content...

Соответственно при нажатии на статью открывается ее полный контент по id.
Но это если в статье есть тупо текст. Но ведь у каждой статьи есть несколько картинок, разные блоки, могут быть списки, разные ссылки, и вообще разная html структура.

Я не понимаю как реализовать хранение этой разной структуры в бд и ее вывод, если изначально я вывожу весь контент по определенному шаблону, где уже прописана вся структура.

Comment: Ну так храните не тупо текст, а html разметку

Comment: Ну это же не совсем правильно хранить в бд весь html, не? Как к примеру редактировать те же картинки?

Comment: Ну а что в этом такого? Да, нужно будет подумать о безопасности. Некоторые теги нужно будет запретить. Другой вариант - это bbcode.

Comment: Попробую) Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то, возможно, поможет хранить 2 экземпляра кода. Один исходный, который вы показываете для создания/редактирования, второй уже "безопасный", который создается на основе исходного в момент сохранения. В таком случае вы сможете оставить в коде всё что нужно для корректного редактирования (к примеру визивиг параметры) и в тоже время спокойно выводите на экран уже обработанный и вычищенный код из второго поля.